# Hilbert-space of system (show condition)

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

We study a quantum particle conned to a
one-dimensional box with walls at the positions ±1.
The Hilbert-space of this system in
the Schrödinger representation is again given by $L_2(-1,1)$. In this Hilbert space, we
consider the two functions $g_0(x):=(1+i)exp(i \pi x)$ and $g_1(x):=exp(i 2 \pi x)$. I shown that $g_0$ and $g_1$ are orthogonal in $L_2([-1,1])$ and that the orthonormal states $\phi_0=\frac{g_0(x)}{2}$ and $\phi_1=\frac{g_1(x)}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Now we now consider a general superposition $\Psi=\alpha \phi_0+\beta \phi_1$ of the two states $\phi_0=\frac{g_0(x)}{2}$ and $\phi_1=\frac{g_1(x)}{\sqrt{2}}.$
Now I have to show that in order for $\Psi$ to be normalized we need that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$. But I'm not sure how to show that. Can anyone help me. What will an argument be? Do I need to proof it the both way?

Comment: In any Hilbert space, given two orthonormal vectors $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, we have $\Vert\alpha\phi_1+\beta\phi_2\Vert^2=|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2$. This can be verified by means of the definition of the norm: $\Vert\psi\Vert^2=\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Aha I see. Can you help me to make the calculations of $||\Psi||^2$?